# Android - create view with coloured background and a transparent shape

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a custom view. This particular view should contain a backgroundcolor, let's say green. On this view there should be a transparent shape.
For example: I have an activity showing some type of listview. This activity calls a dialog box with said custom view. Through the transparent shape the main activity is visible, the rest is overlayed by the solid green background color.
Here's roughly the basic idea:

[image]

How is this possible? Any suggestions?